# Java gradle java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, jar, manifest

Использую Java + Gradle(встроенный в intellij idea)
('gradle' = 'sh gradlew')

В редакторе или при выполнении `gradle run` все работает, но при попытке скомпилировать `gradle build` и запустить `java -jar ./build/libs/LinearServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` я получаю ошибку `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger` при вызове `Logger.getLogger(Main.class);`

Код файла build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'ru.screamt5.linear'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'ru.screamt5.linear.LinearServer.Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.2.0'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': mainClassName,
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}
```

**В чем может быть проблема?**

Comment: Потому что ваша команда запуска ищет классы только в LinearServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Надо либо собрать fat jar, содержащий в себе все зависимости, либо положить в CLASSPATH все зависимости и указать на них при запуске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить *from* в *jar*

```
jar {
    manifest {
        ...
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```